# Group array into array of tuples - odd length

Tags: python, python-2.7

Assuming I have a path such as `/resource/123/resourceb/b/someotherresource/`.  In this case `someotherresource` has no resource id.  This example has 3 resources, but I need to handler anywhere between 1-4 resources.

What is a pythonic way to split it into `[(a,b), (c,d), (e, None)]`

Example:

```
x =  '/resource/123/resourceb/b/someotherresource/'
xplit = x.split('/')
>>> [ 'resource', '123', 'resourceb', 'b', 'someotherresource']
import magic
# ideal result
>>> [ ('resource', '123'), ('resourceb', 'b'), ('someotherresource', None)]
```

I know I can do it the stupid way, but is there a simple way to split & pair an array of odd length ?

Comment: Would adapting [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python) to handle odd numbers do the trick, or is that the stupid way of which you speak.

Comment: @cms_mgr The top answer to that question is sub-optimal as it only works on sequences, not arbitrary iterables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [24]: x
Out[24]: '/resource/123/resourceb/b/someotherresource/'

In [25]: s = x.strip('/').split('/')

In [26]: zip(s[::2], s[1::2] + [None])
Out[26]: [('resource', '123'), ('resourceb', 'b'), ('someotherresource', None)]
```

Comment: +1 I like this one. No strings attached, no dependencies. No lambdas. Just striding slices and zip. Nice

Comment: This does rely on `s` being a list, instead of an arbitrary iterable, which is a little sub-optimal depending on usage. (It also wouldn't scale well to different sized groups).

Answer (score 2):

Use `itertools.izip_longest()` and `iter` magic:

```
import itertools
list(itertools.izip_longest(*[iter(xplit[1:])]*2))
```

We start at index 1 because the leading `/` slash gives you an empty element at the start.

Alternatively, strip of the slashes at start and end:

```
list(itertools.izip_longest(*[iter(x.strip('/').split('/'))]*2))
```

Output:

```
>>> list(itertools.izip_longest(*[iter(x.strip('/').split('/'))]*2))
[('resource', '123'), ('resourceb', 'b'), ('someotherresource', None)]
```

Wrapped up as magic method:

```
import itertools

def split_to_pairs(path):
    path = path.strip('/').split('/')
    return list(itertools.izip_longest(*[iter(path)]*2))
```

Comment: Won't you need `izip_longest` to get the `None` in there?

Comment: @mgilson: indeed, travel tiredness made me slow!

Comment: The fudgesickle that I happened to be snacking on slowed me down ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the `grouper()` [recipie from `itertools`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes):

```
def grouper(n, iterable, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper(3, 'ABCDEFG', 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)
```

(In 2.x, `zip_longest()` is `izip_longest()`)